# Set two state variables based on a single websocket stream on a single click

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks, setstate

The app is streaming price data. I would like to click a button that prints the price when the button was clicked (state variable 1, `guess`) then 5 seconds later print the price again (`actual`, state variable 2)

`price` is the state variable from the datastream

Unfortunately, the value for `guess` is always equal to `actual`, even though `price` has changed.

````
function App() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(null);
  const [guess, setGuess] = useState(null);
  const [actual, setActual] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade");
    ws.onmessage = (event) => {
      let stockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
      let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
      setPrice(price);
    };
  }, []);

  const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
  };

  const makeAGuess = async (price) => {
    setGuess(price);
    await sleep(5000); //wait 5 seconds
  };
  const getActual = async (price) => {
    await sleep(5000); //wait 5 seconds
    setActual(price);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {price && <h2>{price}</h2>}
      {guess && <h2>{guess}</h2>}
      {actual && <h2>{actual}</h2>}
      <button onClick={() => makeAGuess(price).then(getActual(price))}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );```
````

Comment: Please explicit what error in your code? what you want? What you have done

Comment: I would like the value of guess to be the value of price when then button was clicked & the value of actual to be the value of price 5 seconds after the button is clicked. Currently, the guess is set to price, 5 seconds goes by, then actual is set to the same value as guess

Comment: I have been answered your question, If my answer solved your issue please mark as accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useRef` hook to get current value of `state`.
To update with current value. You must update `.current` property's value of `useRef` variable in this case is `priceRef.current`.

```
function App() {
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(null);
    const [guess, setGuess] = useState(null);
    const [actual, setActual] = useState(null);
    const priceRef = useRef(price);
    priceRef.current = price;
    
    useEffect(() => {
      const ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade");
      ws.onmessage = (event) => {
        let stockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
        let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
        setPrice(price);
      };
    }, []);
  
    const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
    };
  
    const makeAGuess = async () => {
      setGuess(price);
      await sleep(5000); //wait 5 seconds
    };
    const getActual = async () => {
      await sleep(5000); //wait 5 seconds
      setActual(priceRef.current);
    };
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {price && <h2>{price}</h2>}
        {guess && <h2>{guess}</h2>}
        {actual && <h2>{actual}</h2>}
        <button onClick={() => { makeAGuess(); getActual() }}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
export default Sidebar;
```